# Buggy pictures in SE chat

Tags: bug, chat, images

I was trading lifehacking pictures in [V'dibarta Bam](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/468/vdibarta-bam) just now, and one of the pictures that was shared didn't show.

The conversation starts [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19135291#19135291), the image I couldn't see is [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19136084#19136084).

<s>I did notice that all of my pictures (which were all visible, to me) were `.png` images, and all of the ones from others that I ***could*** see were also `.png`, but the image that I ***couldn't*** see was `.jpg`, if that makes a difference.</s>

^^^^ No longer true. [This image message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19150341#19150341), from today in Bam, didn't either show, and it actually *was* a `.png` image. So much for that.

The error looked like this:

[image]

And after a reload, like this:

[image]

All images were uploaded through imgur, as far as I could tell.

This was in Chrome; I tried it in incognito mode and got the same error.

When I tried it in Firefox, I got something that looked like this:

[image]

My computer is running Windows 8.1, though I don't quite see how that might be relevant :P .....better too much information, than too little, right?

Comment: I see the error in Chrome on Snow Leopard.

Comment: I can see the picture on Chromium 38.0.2125.111 on Ubuntu.

Comment: This looks more like a failed request due to internets rather than a bug in chat. Perhaps some dropped packets or brief interruption.

Comment: @TravisJ That could be.....but if so, wouldn't a refresh solve the issue? I also switched browsers, and those pictures *still* wouldn't show.

Comment: @Shokhet - Switching browsers will not help with your internet having issues. Also, it could have been not your internet, perhaps there was some issue hosting that image. Since it is no longer reproduceable, this is just speculation - hence the comments :)

Comment: @TravisJ I thought "internets" meant that it was something that didn't load, which would be fixed by refreshing.....but I'm admittedly no expert at the internets, by any stretch of the imagination ;-)

Comment: @Shokhet - If you reload without using `ctrl+f5` then it is possible to reload cached content. If there was some sort of upload error or delay at imgur, perhaps that would result in the issue you described. Again, all speculation :)

Comment: @TravisJ All right, thanks for your help. I've since closed my browser, done other things with my time, and opened it again, and still get the same error :( .....thanks for your speculation, hopefully it might help SE devs or whoever deals with bugs fix this :) ( *assuming it's something that can be fixed* )

Comment: @Shokhet - When I went there I saw the full image. Are you *still* seeing the broken image? Is it possible you are blocking imgur or are somehow being blocked from seeing it? Can you try using `ctrl+f5` on the page to reload?

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console (you can open chrome's console using f12)

Comment: @TravisJ Still broken, though TRiG's image now looks like the second screenshot in my post, rather than the first.

Comment: @TravisJ I don't know how to tell if there's an error in the console. [This](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dhiAn.png) is what I see when I hit f12

Comment: @Shokhet - There is an error there, you can see it next to the red x. There is a >> to the right of elements that you can click and it will offer a selection of tabs. One of them is console. It should contain the message that correlates to the red x.

Comment: @TravisJ I see "2" next to the red X. One thing popped up on the bottom when I clicked on the red X, that says (in part) `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`